# Why does my method fail?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, projectile

---

[image]

Ans is c) 60.

I tried to solve this question by first using the energy conservation law and then the basic equations of projectile motion. Let $v$ be the velocity at point $H$, which is the point at half its maximum height. By energy conservation law,

$$
mgh+\frac{0.4 mv^2}{2}=\frac{mgh}{2}+\frac{mv^2}{2}
$$

From this, we get $v=\sqrt{\frac{10gh}{6}}$.

Since this is the total velocity at point $H$, I took its component in the vertical direction, i.e its $cos \theta$ component. Taking the velocity at highest point in the vertical direction (ie, $0$) as initial velocity $v_0$ and cos$\theta$ component as final velocity $v_f$, we have from the formula for projectile motion

$$
v_f^2 - v_0^2=\left(\sqrt{\frac{10gh}{6}} \cos\theta\right)^2-0^2=2gh/2
$$

By solving this, we have

### $$
\cos\theta=\sqrt{3/5}
$$

This is not the correct answer. What is wrong?

Comment: A diagram is indispensable when working physics problems, as you can see from alfred's answer.  Where feasible, draw a picture of the problem.  If the picture is incorrect, your instructor will be better able to identify any misconceptions that you have, BEFORE you are tested on the material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution to the problem, you have not clearly defined what you mean by $\theta$ and as a result you might have confused yourself: in your solution, $\theta$ is the angle that the velocity makes with the horizontal axis at point $H$, ie the point where the height is at half its maximum. Furthermore, this point is when the particle is going downwards according to your $v_f^2 - v_0^2$ equation and this might not have been what you want. However, what the question is asking for is the *angle of projection*. With this in mind, try again and see if you can find the correct answer.

A diagram like the one I have drawn here will be very helpful in the future when you are dealing with any Physics problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did confuse myself and thought the angle of projection would be same everywhere,thereby,making my answer meaningless.